# WPF Prism How to relate Module, View and Region with Unity container

Tags: wpf, prism

I am having difficulty in finding a relation between a given Module and Views(plain WPF user control) which has been Registered to different regions using this Module (in IModule Initialize() method).

When a Request comes to load a module `IModuleManager.LoadModule`  is being used the first time to load the module. First time loading a module is not as issue.

Now, another request comes to load a module,which was already loaded so I can not use `IModuleManager.LoadModule` method, (User will just give ModuleName).

Now I have to find out what are the its Regions (need to clear them first) and its View (need to load them in there respective Regions).
So I need a map , kind of triplet, of Module-View-Region and create this triplet first time when IModuleManager.LoadModuleCompleted gets triggered. Later I can use this to find the regions and views.

Used `IRegionViewRegistry.ContentRegistered` but it just gives (Regions and Views). But no way to relate it to ModuleName(of Module Info) and `IModuleManager.LoadModuleCompleted` just gives `ModuleInfo` (no way to find out Regions and Views it uses)

Comment: Couldn't really understand what you question is. Can you add an example that show the specific issue?

Comment: It is simple. I need to display views in a Module. User will select module name from drop down list. First time it works using IModuleManager.LoadModule(string ModuleName). If I want to display the same module again(in the same region after clearing the previously displayed module) IModuleManager.LoadModule is not going to work. I donw know the views and regions contained in that Module. I know just ModuleName and I need to display it's view , even I don't know the region? I just know the moduleName. So how I can discover it's views and region and use RegionManager to display these